# Command did not execute successfully due to an unexpected exception. Please check output window for additional information

Tags: android

when i click on AVD, a prompt will appear with "Command did not execute successfully due to an unexpected exception. Please check output window for additional information" when i see the output window a failure message will appear:-
 below is the error log

```
[failure] could not find file 'c\Users\braintech\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile158.AssemblyAttributes.cs'.
[failure] could not find file 'c\Users\braitech\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin.ios,Version=v1.0,AssemblyAttributes.cs'.
[failure] could not find file 'c\Users\braitech\AppData\Local\Temp\MonoAndroid,Version=v5.0,AssemblyAttributes.cs'.
```

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same problem as you when I was working with Xamarin in visual studios. Every time I clicked on the android sdk manager I would get this error. There are a few solutions that I found for this problem. However Only one of them actually worked for me:

Possible solution: 
Go to where the sdk folder is installed. Mine is installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`. Once you're there, go into the `temp`folder. Grab the zip file named "tools_r24.0.1-windows" (version number might be different). extract it somewhere, copy the the "tools" folder that it creates and paste it in the sdk file location, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`. Replace the old one. Restart VS and it should work.

This information was provided by MarcMagnin, https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/43688/android-sdk-manager-and-avd-will-not-open-neither-will-my-xaml-layouts

Comment: The file path was the same for me (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\ `). Inside there was a `temp` folder, but it was empty. Fortunately (!!!) I had another unpacked `android-sdk\tools` folder in my user home directory, as described by S List below. When I copied it over and restarted visual studio `Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager` worked. (Much to my relief)

Answer (score 1):

I think I came across this problem because I had rolled back the latest android platform and build tools when they broke my build. It seems to have deleted the Android tools altogether, rather than rolling them back.

So, I checked in my `android-sdk` folder, and sure enough, the `tools` subfolder was missing.

From various installs at various different times, I have an `sdk` folder next to the `android-sdk` folder at `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`, and this `sdk` folder still contained `tools`.
So I just copied `sdk\tools` and all its contents into the neighbouring `android-sdk` folder, and the problem was solved.

Comment: Worked as described (and made me very happy). See also my comment on the accepted answer above.